# vaadin sends a post request for every action taken

Tags: grails, vaadin, grails-plugin

I'm evaluating Vaadin plugin for Grails and one of the many concers is performance.

I developed a trivial application having a tree set and every time i click on an item a form is filled in, the fields are manually edited and when i push a save button the change is persisted.
Although I am very impressed with the speed i managed to implement such application i have a concern regarding performances with the future real application. 
In particular I can see that for every action I take (clicking on an item, collapsing the tree, etc.) a post is sent:

http://myhost.org/fooWithVaadin/UIDL/?v-uiId=0

Is there a way to avoid this? I tried to apply setImmediate(false) to every component but I don't see any change. Is [Snappy](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/snappy) the right way to go?

Ideally what I want to achieve is to have a complete model running on the client site and have communication with the server either when is strictly necessary (Eg. to retrieve information that was not available when the application was loaded) or when the "Save" button is pushed. Is this realistic?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: That's why I migrated my projects to pure GWT some time ago. Vaadin is great for local network applications, but it is really slow for real world internet applications (by real world I mean slow connections and stuff).

Comment: I'm reading the chapter regarding "Client side application". It looks interesting, did you evaluate this approach?

Comment: It looks nice, but for that I prefer to stick with pure GWT (I like to have fine control of my code). But that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

this is the negative aspect of Vaadin, you do not have things fully under control. We also gave up Vaadin and went pure GWT. http://www.outsourced.sk/1872/building-scalable-cloud-app-using-gwt-jboss-mongodb-on-openshift-part-2-vaadin/